# DataGridView cell causing validation on simple arrow keys

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Why does `DataGridView` raise `CellValidating` event upon simple navigation through arrow keys? How can I prevent it? Here is the key information about `DataGridView` state when it calls `CellValidating`:

```
EditMode = EditOnKeyStrokeOrF2
IsCurrentCellInEditMode = False
e.FormattedValue = [Same as the current value of the cell]
```

As you can see, user has not triggered any editing operation. He's just moving across the cells by pressing right-arrow key. One would not expect validation to occur at this point, right?

Note: Examining call stack shows that `KeyDown`event triggers a `CommitEdit` call, which in turn raises `OnCellValidating`.

Comment: Perhaps this is a silly question, but why does it matter if it calls `CellValidating`? If the user has made no changes, then the validation will succeed because there have been no changes since the last time it was validated. Is it an issue with the validation being a time consuming task?

Comment: @Origin: I have setup a rule in `CellValidating` event handler that makes sure the input value is between 1 and 12 for the Month column. Since my `DataGridView` allows user to add new rows, if user moves selection into the new row (that one that has * in the row header), and then tries to move back, the handler won't allow them because the current value of the Month cell in the new row is empty string, which is not between 1 and 12. Other than this specific problem, I feel that in general validation should occur when user causes a change in the cell value, not by simply passing through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like it or not, this is the way things are desigend to work. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating%28v=vs.90%29) on `CellValidating`:

> Occurs when a cell loses input focus, enabling content validation.

And to make it complete [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidated%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) on `CellValidated`:

> Occurs after the cell has finished validating.

The most direct and readable solution is probably to put a line like this at the start of the `CellValidating` event:

```
if (!dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)  return;
```

One reason for the designed behaviour could be the case where a user input is actually needed to create a valid cell value. Not your case, but still a conceivable requirement.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, `e.FormattedValue` is not `null` in my case, so the above 4 solutions would not work. `IsCurrentCellDirty` however makes sense. How would you compare using `IsCurrentCellDirty` to using `IsCurrentCellInEditMode` instead?

Comment: Sorry, I got that part wrong; I'll edit the answer. As for the other question: This doesn't sound right as [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.iscurrentcellineditmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says: _A DataGridViewCheckBoxCell that has focus is always in edit mode. If the current cell hosts an editing control and IsCurrentCellInEditMode is true, you can retrieve the editing control through the EditingControl property._ So it would always be true while tabbing through..

Comment: Looks like `IsCurrentCellDirty` is more appropriate candidate here. Thanks for your input. BTW, did you notice that the MSDN excerpt you copied is talking about `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` only, not other column types? Just pointing it out because in my case `IsCurrentCellInEditMode` is `false` if I simply tab through the cell.