# Why my checkbox value not set to true although it is checked?

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

I have a list of checkbox that represents column names. The user needs to pick which column that he/she wants to be displayed in datagridview. There is also a checkbox in header that when clicked will set that all the checkbox that represents column names will be selected automatically. The problem is at condition `if (cell.Value != null)`. The `cell.Value` is set to false. So the messagebox does not pop up. Why is this happening and how can i solve them. Thank you in advance.

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = row.Cells[0] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
            if (cell.Value != null)
            {
                if (cell.Value == cell.TrueValue)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("checked");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the code when the user checked the header checkbox.

```
    private void checkboxHeader_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1[0, i].Value = ((CheckBox)dataGridView1.Controls.Find("checkboxHeader", true)[0]).Checked;
        }
        dataGridView1.EndEdit();
    }
```

Comment: Make sure that the values are not being _resetted_ on the `Page_Load` (or similar) event. When this happens (PostBack), it could be messing with the state of your controls/elements (i.g., if you bind your GridView on Page_Load).

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34090190/c-sharp-datagridview-checkbox-checked-event?rq=1) and also [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263912/datagridview-cell-causing-validation-on-simple-arrow-keys/27280419#27280419) !

Comment: When i change it to type string then it all works fine. Thanks for the replies guys